# WSO2 Identity server 4.5 saml2 demo

Tags: wso2, single-sign-on, identity, saml-2.0

I wonder if anyone who has the saml2 based sso sample ,the documentation's link of wso2's official website for identity server 4.5 seemed only can be used in the version of 4.0.http://docs.wso2.org/display/IS450/Setting+Up+SAML2+Based+SSO

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a sample in the svn [1] of Identity server 4.5.0.  I think it would probably works.

[1] http://svn.wso2.org/repos/wso2/carbon/platform/branches/4.2.0/products/is/4.5.0/modules/samples/sso/SSOAgentSample

Answer (score 0):

The following link helped me to try out WSO2 Identity server. It has svn link for sample source code and steps to execute it.

http://sureshatt.blogspot.in/2012/08/saml20-sso-with-wso2-identity-server.html

Comment: Note that [link-only answers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info) are discouraged, SO answers should be the end-point of a search for a solution (vs. yet another stopover of references, which  tend to get stale over time). Please consider adding a stand-alone synopsis here, keeping the link as a reference.